# Updating a query set - Python Django - Postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, psql

I am trying to delete a query set -

`Profile.objects.filter(val=False).delete()`

This command runs fine on my local machine, however, when I run it on production (hosted on heroku) I get the following error:

`django.db.utils.InternalError: cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction`

I am assuming it is some sort of a psql permissions issue but I am not too sure. Any idea as to why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would make sure that the username/password you use to connect to the database server in your settings.py file has delete permission in the database.

Comment: This also happens when you are connected to a replication slave DB server. AFAIR on Heroku they call them followers.